# Pass class as argument

Tags: oop, api, class-design

I have an api method I need to call. It has 10 parameters. I have attempted to make a class that holds all the information the method requires. Can I then simply pass the object into the method?

```
myAPIMethod(myClass);
```

Does it work that easily?

Comment: Do you mean passing the class or an object that is an instance of the class? If the latter, then yes. Also, what language are you using, Java, C++?

Comment: Which language?  The answer is almost certainly "no, it's not that simple", but we might be able to suggest something if we knew more details.  Can you change the API?

Comment: I can't change the API and I am using ActionScript3. @Zhehao: I did mean an instance of the class.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, it doesn't work that way. If a method has 10 parameters, you will have to pass 10 arguments to it.

If you have control of the API, you can refactor it to accept a single object instead.

If you don't have control of the API, you can write a method along the lines of

```
public void CallAPI(MyClass args)
{
   myAPIMethod(args.Arg1, args.Arg2); // whatever args are needed for the method
}
```

Then your code can use your class and this method to invoke the API. It could be a cleaner approach than invoking the API method directly with 10 arguments in multiple places in your application. But, this depends on what the method is and how you're using it.

Comment: Would I be able to assign CallAPI() to a submit button's click event? (as3)

Comment: @steve I don't know, unfortunately. I'm not familiar with ActionScript3. But I imagine you could call it inside the click event's handler.

Answer (score 1):

You create an instance of the class, called an object, and pass the object - thus "object oriented programming"

If your method requires 10 parameters though, you must pass 10 parameters. You can't just pass an object that contains 10 parameters unless you rewrite your method.

Comment: I can think of several reasons why I would want to pass a class around as an argument. And that's before I think of languages where classes _are_ objects.

Comment: @Frank Shearer - I edited because you are right that there are times when you want to pass a class, but based on the problem description, I thought it was highly unlikely that he actually needed to pass a class.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no, you can't do that.

This is not quite what you were looking for, but in some languages (e.g. Python) you can create something called a [*partial application*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application) (sometimes incorrectly called [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)). This allows you to create a new function that calls another function, but with some of the params pre-specified.